# What are those "timeline" dashboards are called in video/audio editors?

Tags: time-signatures

I'm trying to make a similar thing for a web app, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's already open source software out there.

The idea: User plays a youtube video on one of my web pages -- a widget (bar) below the youtube video (don't know what it's called, other than "timeline") progresses left-to-right (with a vertical line indicating position in time), with an interval of 5 seconds per inch as an example. I'll be putting guitar tabs and/or sheet music on this timeline, for what it's worth.

What is the widget called? Are there any open source (js/jquery) versions?

Edit: They look like this (bottom): https://mondrian.mashable.com/wp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F11%252Fsoundslice-640.jpg%252Ffull-fit-in__1200x2000.jpg?signature=Ppr7X2CvAyjumG9W4En31tmY-Ac=&source=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com

Comment: This question is probably better suited to the ELL SE, but Wiki calls this a "playback bar." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_bar#:~:text=A%20progress%20bar%20is%20a,%2C%20file%20transfer%2C%20or%20installation.&text=The%20concept%20can%20also%20be,duration%20of%20a%20media%20file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer who made the app in your screenshot (and also the musician featured in the tab in your screenshot). :-)

To answer your question: I just call it the timeline.

By the way, the technology featured in your screenshot is [licensable](https://www.soundslice.com/licensing/), so I encourage you not to reinvent the wheel!